# Orthogonal projection of vector with a special structure.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an $N \times 1$ vector with $M$ non-zero elements and $N-M$ zeros. I'm orthogonally projecting this vector onto an $M$ dimensional subspace. Now, since my vector is technically composed of $M$ elements (the remaining are all zeros), does that mean I'm projecting $M$ elements onto the $M$ dimensional subspace?. Is there any way of getting my original vector back by reversing the projection operation?.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on *which* $M$-dimensional subspace you're projecting onto. For example, let's say you have $N=2$ (so that the space we're working in is $\mathbb{R}^2$) and $M=1$, and your vector is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
If you are projecting onto the $x$-axis
$$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a\\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \;\middle|\; a\in\mathbb{R}\right\},$$
which is a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then you are "preserving" the non-zero entries of your vector, but if you are projecting onto the $y$-axis
$$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ a \end{bmatrix} \;\middle|\; a\in\mathbb{R}\right\},$$
which is also a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then you are "killing" the non-zero entries.

Comment: @ Zev My projection does not preserve the non-zero elements. Does that mean I can't go back to the original vector?.

Comment: Yes; you are "losing information" in the projection.